# Upload image URI to Cloudinary

Tags: javascript, cloudinary

I've done some looking at the Cloudinary API and upload examples for NodeJS, and it looks like the server-side uploads use a file path. Meanwhile, the client-side uploads require a frontend input tag. I already have a frontend for users to select and crop a picture to their liking, and this gives me a data URI. I'd like to save this file to Cloudinary without having to use their built in frontend option. Is this possible? This would basically mean that I would be able to call some kind of upload function that can take a URI or file blob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloudinary supports uploading files using a data-URI encoded string too. 
Please make sure that you send your content as a Data-URI as explained here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme.

For example, in Node.js:

> cloudinary.uploader.upload("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7",
>   function(result) {console.log(result)});

Comment: It is giving me an error 
http_code
:
400
message
:
"Missing required parameter - file"

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my end, the above code works for me. Please share some more information, your Cloudinary SDK version, the exact code you used, and any other information that may be relevant. Alternatively, please open a support ticket, and Cloudinary's support team are always happy to help.

Comment: Was searching for this for hours. They should have documented about this.

Comment: It's actually already documented in the KBs section: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/203125741-Can-I-upload-using-DATA-URI-BASE64-

Comment: Hi, do you have an idea what the final request looks like ? I'd like to implement this using fetch, but the doc is unclear about the actual request that should be sent.

Comment: You just need to make sure the data is escaped. Here's a curl example for an unsigned upload: `curl "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/mycloudname/image/upload?upload_preset=mypreset&file=data%3Aimage/gif%3Bbase64%2CR0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"`. Note that signed uploads require generating a signature which must be calculated on the server side, as it's based on your account's api_secret which must not be in your client-side code.